# Only scrape new items in Scrapy without a particular URL for each

Tags: python, scrapy

I wrote a spider in Scrapy and I like to scrape only new items. I know DeltaFetch but I don't think it's possible in my case.
I have urls. For each url, I have items with different values. I'd like to upgrade only these items.

My spider:

```
import json
import scrapy
import re
import pkgutil

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from auctions_results.items import AuctionItem
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

from datetime import datetime

class GlenMarchSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'auctions_results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_file = pkgutil.get_data(
            "auctions_results", "json/input/scrape_db_complete.json")
        self.data = json.loads(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['gm_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []

        for caritem in response.css("div.car-item-border"):
            data = AuctionItem()    

            data["auction_house"] = caritem.css("div.auctionHouse::text").extract_first().split("-", 1)[0].strip()    
            auctionurl = caritem.css("div.view-auction a::attr(href)").extract_first()

            data["image_urls"] = caritem.css("div.view-auction a img::attr(src)").extract_first()

            data["image_cloud"] = None

            item['results'].append(data)

        yield item
```

I have a pipeline for images:

```
import scrapy

from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class DownloadImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for result in item['results']:
            image_url = result['image_urls']
            if image_url is not None:
                request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url)
                yield request
```

I'd like to upgrade only the new items in `results` including images
Output sample:

```
"gm_url": "https://www.sitetoscrape.com/page",
    "results": [
        {
            "auction_house": "Artcurial",
            "auction_url": null,
            "image_urls": "https://www.example.com/img.jpg",
            "image_cloud": "https://res.cloudinary.com/img.jpg"
        },
        {
            "auction_house": "Christies",
            "auction_url": "http://www.example.com",
            "image_urls": "https://www.example.com/img2.jpg",
            "image_cloud": "https://res.cloudinary.com/img2.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "images": [
        {
            "url": "https://www.example.com/img.jpg",
            "path": "full/img.jpg",
            "checksum": "212a6287eed95943a1d51ebc662c44be"
        },
        {
            "url": "https://www.example.com/img2.jpg",
            "path": "full/img2.jpg",
            "checksum": "ff51dc0a36747bdf022feb83c19a3109"
        }
    ]
} ...
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: "How can I do that ?" -> Programing code for that ... If you have a problem try to reduce it to simple and exact problem to ask for it, not to demand code. You posted a lot of insignificant code for your question

Comment: I post this insignificant code to help understanding the "architecture" of the spider. The inherent question is about the possibility for DeltaFetch to do that or not because there is very little documentation about this addon.

Comment: So have you tried some code for your question?

Comment: I add the DeltaFetch plugin and enabled it in `settings.py` and it scraped everything, even the second time. All items are scraped.